# Website inspect element different from the actual devices (React/CSS-Sass, MediaQueries)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, media-queries

I made my website responsive using media queries and I deployed the website on netlify to test it out on my devices. The positioning of things are messed up on iPhone and iPad, and I tried playing around with px, em, and rem on some of the properties, but cannot figure out why it is not being responsive.

I have used media queries in the past and on my phone it usually looks exactly how it looks in the inspect element.

the website is here :
https://5f4d22cb33e64e0007ea75ad--musing-payne-80bb82.netlify.app/

here are screenshots of the differences between iPhone 8 inspect element and my actual iPhone 8:

[image]

[image]

and since the project is small and I do not know how to condense this problem as I do not know where it is here is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/Calebm5577/movie-search-app

There are >src>CSS with 3 folders and 1 sass file in each, Abstracts folder has the media queries, and src>components with my only 2 react components.

Comment: A response for what usually causes this rather than new code would suffice as I am still trying things and I didnt leave the code in the post.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache on your phone?

Comment: Yes just tried it, same issue. I also just put another media queries project on netlify and checked on my phone and this other one works fine, so I think the problem is something with this projects rather than my phone